# Wordpress PayPal oder failed error, CreditCardGateway.php:405

Tags: woocommerce, paypal

- WooCommerce PayPal Payments 1.9.3
- WooCommerce  6.9.3
- Wordpress 6.0.2 OceanWP latest version

> Failed to process the payment. Please try again or contact the shop admin. [UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY] The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-PAYMENT_DENIED CreditCardGateway.php:405 [UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY] The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-PAYMENT_DENIED OrderEndpoint.php:313 Order status changed from Pending payment to Failed.

Answer (score 0):

> PAYMENT_DENIED

This is a normal business error, not a technical problem. It simply means the payment was denied by PayPal.

If you are testing payments yourself, ensure the card and its address, email, phone number, the IP address used, etc are not associated with the receiving PayPal business account in any way. Payments to your own account are not permitted in the live/production environment.

Comment: i have tested it using other credit cards also. but the same problem.